# ActiveRecord scope - nested associations through two different foreign keys

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application, this is the schema:

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :origin, class_name: 'Station'
  belongs_to :destination, class_name: 'Station'
  belongs_to :vehicle

  has_many :trips 
end

class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :route
end

class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :origins, foreign_key: :origin_id, class_name: "Route"
  has_many :destinations, foreign_key: :destination_id, class_name: "Route"
end
```

I'm trying to construct a scope within `Trip` that fetches all the trips that have either flown to OR from a particular `Station`. Right now, I'm accomplishing this `.new_york` scope as follows:

```
scope :to_new_york,       -> { joins(route: :destination).where(["stations.name = ?", "New York City"]) }
scope :from_new_york,     -> { joins(route: :origin).where(["stations.name = ?", "New York City"]) }
scope :new_york,          -> { to_new_york + from_new_york }
```

Since I never intend to use `to_new_york` and `from_new_york` on their own (I only care about a collection that contains **both** groups), is there a way to write a single `.new_york` scope that does both jobs without having to write the component `.to_` and `.from_` scopes?